# How to compare two dataframes element-wise?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare two dataframes in an element-wise manner in order to find which elements in dataframe one are less than those in dataframe two.

DataFrame One:

[image]

DataFrame Two:

[image]

In this case, the only elements that should return `True` should be elements on `Column 130_x` for Indexes 0 and 1. The rest should return `False`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your dataframes as text, not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify the dataframes. You can use the underlying numpy array:

```
df1.lt(df2.values)
```

Output:

```
   126_x  127_x  128_x  129_x  130_x
0  False  False  False  False   True
1   True  False  False  False   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to change the column names

```
df1.columns = df2.columns
```

Or here we use replace

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace('_x','_y')
s = df1.eq(df2).all(1)
s.index[s]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `df1 < df2` but your column names needs to be the same.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data1 = StringIO("""
126_x,127_x,128_x,129_x,130_x
0.0,0.04898,0.359184,0.004082,0.134694
0.0,0.04898,0.359184,0.004082,0.134694
""")

data2 = StringIO("""
126_y,127_y,128_y,129_y,130_y
0.0,0.0,0.175439,0.0,0.166667
0.006579,0.0,0.269737,0.0,0.223684
""")

df1 = pd.read_csv(data1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(data2)

# column header needs to be the same
df2.columns = df1.columns

print(df1 < df2)

#    126_x  127_x  128_x  129_x  130_x
# 0  False  False  False  False   True
# 1   True  False  False  False   True
```

---

> In this case the only elements that should return True should be elements on Column 130_x for Indexes 0 and 1. The rest should return False.

That's not correct, there is another cell (Column `126_y`, Row 2) which would be true: 
`0.006579 > 0.0`.